# PHP files not automatically loaded in nginx

Tags: php, nginx

When I try to access my site I have to manually type index.php at the end of the url. I'm trying to have automatically load my index.php file when accessing the site. My nginx config file looks like this.

```
server {
        listen 80;


        root /var/www/html/myapp/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP

        server_name _;

        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            index index.html index.htm index.php;
#            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
            try_files $uri $uri/ = 404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

        error_page 404 /index.php;


        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for laravel Apps, you need to have the below in your nginx conf

```
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Comment: is this a laravel application ?

Comment: I have this deployed in dozens of laravel installations and its working flawlessly

Comment: That's wonderful, it just didn't work for me. Kept getting access denied error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's the fact that I have the app directory structure like. /var/www/html/app/public as the root. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: the public folder should be the root document, that how I configure it always